# How to check URL with different path is same a API

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm have two `url` bellow:

`https://example.com/detail/2/task/update`

`https://example.com/detail/4/task/delete`

Both are same form of a API:

`https://example.com/detail/{detail_id}/task/{action}`

I need put a action to intercepter for above API

My question how to check both `url` above are same form of a API

Comment: did you try the answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match the URL. I have created a regex for you, please try and let me know if that works

```
https:\/\/example\.com\/detail\/\w*\/task\/\w*
```

You can even try to validate the regex using the below website.

https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A programmatic logic check? Use a common Boolean value to check if it is set to yes?